# How to load static images using Node.js and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to create a simple browser-based game.

This is my development script in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development parcel index.html --no-hmr"
  },
```

This is the `canvas` defined in my `index.html`:

```
<div id="game-wrapper">
    <canvas id="game-canvas" height="512" width="288"></canvas>
    <script src="src/game.js"></script>
</div>
```

I am using Node.js for my back-end, and would like load in some static images (e.g., sprites) in my `public` folder and draw them on this canvas.

This is my `src/game.js`:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('game-canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

let image = new Image();
image.src = "public/image.png";

context.drawImage(image, x, y);
```

If I do this, I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute `drawImage` on `CanvasRenderingContext2D`: The HTMLImageElement provided is in the `broken` state.
```

How should I go about this?

Comment: The `public` folder is usually not included in client-side URL paths. Try `/image.png` instead. We do need to know about your setup though; how does your server code look like?

Comment: @ChrisG I'm not sure what you mean by "server code". Currently, I'm just running in my local environment using the `watch` script above.

Comment: It's a local server though, those are commonly used for development. Also, I just saw that you're probably trying to draw the image too early, before it is loaded; setting the src doesn't wait for that. You need to use `image.onload = function () { ... }` and draw the image inside that.

Comment: @ChrisG I think you are right. I modified my code to `image.onload = function(){context.drawImage(image, x, y)};`, where `x` and `y` are constantly being updated in a loop, however nothing is being drawn. The weird part is that if I do `context.fillText("Score: " + score, 10, canvas.height - 20);`, I can see the text being displayed.

Comment: You need to make sure you're using the right path for the image. I assume your site is being served at something like `localhost:8080`; going to `localhost:8080/image.png` should display the image. If not, you need to figure out the correct path; until then, troubleshooting the JS code is a waste of time.